# How to make a background job always print "Done" in Bash?

Tags: bash

I've noticed that sometimes a background job does not print `Done` unless I press `Enter`.

Taking `git gc` for example,

```
git gc --force --prune=now &
```

The output is like,

```
Enumerating objects: 574964, done.
Counting objects: 100% (574964/574964), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (156394/156394), done.
Writing objects: 100% (574964/574964), done.
Total 574964 (delta 296425), reused 574891 (delta 296375), pack-reused 0
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking connectivity: 574964, done.
Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 87696, done.
```

I don't know if it has really ended or not until I press `Enter`. If it's ended, it prints

```
[1]+  Done                    git gc --force --prune=now
```

If I don't press `Enter` or any other key, it seems frozen and just does not print "Done" as if it's still running.

For a simple background job like `echo hello &`, it prints "Done" immediately after `hello` is printed.

```
[1] 17647
hello
[1]+  Done                    echo hello
```

I'd like to know what leads to the different behaviors and how I can make it always print "Done" automatically when the job finishes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [man bash](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> The shell learns immediately whenever a job changes state.  Normally, bash **waits until it is  about  to  print  a
> prompt**  before  reporting changes in a job's status so as to not interrupt any other output.  If **the `-b` option** to
> the `set` builtin command is enabled, bash reports such changes immediately.

Comment: Thanks! `set -b` and `set +b` solve my problem.